# tests that rely on residuals

Tags: regression

This might be an r question, which I think is not allowed here, but I figured I would try in case it is ok. There are a series of tests which as I understand it rely on residuals. One example of this is the Breusch-Pagan test. This generates apparent results from that (and the documentation seems to require a regression model rather than residuals).

```
# load the dataset
data(mtcars)
# fit a regression model
model <- lm(mpg~disp+hp, data=mtcars)
library(lmtest)
# perform Breusch-Pagan Test
bptest(model)
```

Is the code extracting the residuals or am I wrong in assuming you need residuals for this test (the comments I read seem pretty clear it is run on the residuals).

Comment: Yes, the test uses residuals and the function - which you can inspect by writing `bptest` in R - extracts the residuals for us. Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/468778/contradictory-results-between-breusch-pagan-test-and-goldfeld-quandt-test-in-pyt

Comment: Thanks. Thank you also for editing it, I did not realize [code][/code] did not work (or what does work for code). Is it true that questions about R are generally not allowed here? I ask because I have found many R questions on this board in years past (I am new to R and learn a lot about it from past posts on this forum).

Comment: On R questions: this guidance is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic "If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here; if it's about the implementation of an algorithm, routine data processing, or details of the language, then please refer to the collection of links to resources we maintain."

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ChristophHanck's comment, you can check the [source code for bptest](https://rdrr.io/cran/lmtest/src/R/bptest.R) and in it you see that a formula and a data frame can be applied:

```
bptest(mpg~disp+hp, data=mtcars)

studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  mpg ~ disp + hp
BP = 4.0861, df = 2, p-value = 0.1296
```

Underneath the code, there's two parts. If you provide a lm object, it will extract the x and y, refit the formula using lm.fit. After which, it extracts the residuals from the lm.fit object and calculates the relevant statistics. These are the relevant lines:

```
resi <- lm.fit(X,y)$residuals
  sigma2 <- sum(resi^2)/n

  if(studentize)
  {
    w <- resi^2 - sigma2
    aux <- lm.fit(Z, w)    
    bp <- n * sum(aux$fitted.values^2)/sum(w^2)
    method <- "studentized Breusch-Pagan test"
  }
  else
  {
    f <- resi^2/sigma2 -1
    aux <- lm.fit(Z, f)
    bp <- 0.5 * sum(aux$fitted.values^2)
    method <- "Breusch-Pagan test"
  }

  names(bp) <- "BP"
  df <- c("df" = aux$rank - 1)
  RVAL <- list(statistic = bp,
      parameter = df,
      method = method,
      p.value= pchisq(bp, df, lower.tail = FALSE),
      data.name = dname)
```

Comment: Thanks very much.Now that I know that, I really am new to R being a SAS user all my life, I started to look at other tests that I had questions on such as Breusch-Godfrey serial correlation. I don't understand a lot of the code, but I can see where it pulls residuals. What language is R written in, I need to try to understand better what lies behind it. is it possible to find the algorithms that lie behind the code as well? When results vary from SAS I (or my team that is also learning R) need to understand why.

Comment: R is a programming language, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language) . Some of the base functions would call a C or fortran code.. It's is a good question what is the algorithm behind the code..normally in the manual or vignette the authors will indicate where the algo comes  from, for example this bptest,https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmtest/lmtest.pdf

Comment: Using this example, bptest, it extracts the residuals (resi), finds the mean of the residuals (sigma2) and then performs the auxillary regression.. So I guess if you have a clue on how it should be implemented, and have a knowledge of what each function does, it will make sense

Comment: @user54285 This book might be helpful to make the transition from SAS to R easier: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461406846

Comment: thanks. I have a group of programmers on my team (I am the one who knows the statistics and figures out what we need to do). I will try to learn it, but I am sure they will learn it far faster.:) I really appreciate the help.